# how to read parquet schema in non mapreduce java program

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, parquet

Is there a way to direct read Parquet file column names by getting metadata without mapreduce. Please give some example. I am using snappy as compression codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either ParquetFileReader or use existing tool https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools for reading parquet file using command line.